# why data column shows as modelname object(1) when I refer foreign key? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I am trying to get data from the model the column which I refer foreign key shows as  object(value). why not value alone?..

say for example in y model i am using foreign key of x model column (id). it showing as x object(1) instead of 1.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` will lazily load the object it refers to, so if you have a `ForeignKey` named `foo` that refers to the `Foo` model, it does not return the primary key of that `Foo` object, but the `Foo` object itself.

In the column it will call the `__str__` on that object, and the default for the `__str__` is the name of the model, with between brackets the primary key, so `ModelName(pk)` with *`ModelName`* the name of the model, and *`pk`* the primary key of the object.

You can change this behavior by overriding the `__str__` method, for example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

Where `Foo` is the class that is *referenced* by the `ForeignKey`, this is not (per se) the class where the `ForeignKey` is defined.

Usually `__str__` however should not return the primary key, but for example the name of the object, or something similar.

If you want to use the value stored in the database as foreign key, you can use `foo_id`, with *`foo`* the name of the `ForeignKey`.